# Геттеры и сеттеры для статических полей

Tags: java

Вопрос, возможно, глупый, но всё же... Нужны ли геттеры и сеттеры для статических полей, или их лучше объявлять `public`?

Т.е, какой из вариантов лучше?

**1 вариант:**

```
public abstract class SomeClass {
    public static boolean isReadOnly = false;
}
```

и далее использовать `SomeClass.isReadOnly = true;`

**2 вариант:**

```
public abstract class SomeClass {
    private static boolean isReadOnly = false;

    public static boolean isReadOnly() {
        return isReadOnly;
    }

    public static void setReadOnly(boolean isReadOnly) {
        SomeClass.isReadOnly = isReadOnly;
    }
}
```

и далее использовать `SomeClass.setReadOnly(true);`

Comment: Кому-то нужны, кому-то нет. По разному бывает. Всё как для обычных полей.

Comment: @Sergey, для обычных полей, как правило, обычно нужны (за исключением особых случае). Интересно, есть ли какое-нибудь правило для статических полей

Comment: Если вы разрабатываете большой стаей обезьян, которые легко что-то могут сломать - это необходимо, если писать в одно лицо - смысла никакого.

Comment: @DaysLikeThis,  я знакома с правилом именования констант. Но у меня не константа, а изменяемое поле.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Область видимости поля нужно определять исходя из того, где оно будет использовано. (ваш К.О.)

В вашем случае с примитивным типом никакой разницы нет. Вы в обоих вариантах позволяете модифицировать переменную.

Если, к примеру, вам нужны какие-то дополнительные проверки при записи, тогда имеет смысл использовать приватное поле и сеттер. Или если у вас поле-объект и вы не хотите давать ссылку на него напрямую (как в случае с `public`), тогда имеет смысл использовать приватное поле и геттер, который возвращает копию объекта.

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю к уже сказанному.
Геттеры и сеттеры позволяют более гибко избавиться от поля вообще, не меняя внешний API. То есть, вызываться будет сеттер, но он уже не будет сетить в поле и поля уже не будет, а будет какая-то другая логика.
А вообще, советую почитать книгу Джошуа Блоха Effective Java.